# How to theme the $item in views-view-grid.tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming

I'm just beginning to learn theming Drupal 7, and have encountered something I can't seem to find any info on (and my experiments have no effect).

In tao/rubik theme, and in many others there is the  views-view-grid.tpl.php template which arranges the resulting items from a view in a grid design.

Now, at the very end, after splitting into rows and columns there is a print $item which is the section that prints the actual node content/teaser in the grid square. I'm assuming the content is a node, since this is what I set the view block to display, also I set it to display the full content of that single node.

However, no matter what I do, I can't seem to modify the template of this node... how should the template be called? should it be placed somewhere special?

What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure if it's just a typo in the question but in Drupal 7 the template naming convention would mean the file should be called views--view--grid.tpl.php

Comment: Did you click on "Rescan template files" in Views >> Style Information >> Theme:Information ?

Comment: Hi, Copied the template name directly from the template folder. As to the Rescan, Yes I did... change to the Grid template did indeed have effect, but not on the $item which is another level in, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to theme the display of a node, those templates have names like node.tpl.php, node--NID.tpl.php, node--TYPE.tpl.php, etc.  Lots of information on templates can be found [here](http://drupal.org/node/1089656)

Comment: Also, in the view edit form, check for Advanced -> Other -> Theme: Information

Comment: missed that single - ... now it works. how stupid of me.

Comment: we've all been there; no one is stupid when it comes to missed dashes in drupal templates!